# MiniProfiler Start and StartNew not Working as per Documentation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, miniprofiler

I am following [these instructions](https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/AspDotNet) to attach the MVC `MiniProfiler` to my project.

Steps taken:

- `Install-Package MiniProfiler.Mvc5 -IncludePrerelease`
- `using StackExchange.Profiling` in `Global.asax.cs`
- `MiniProfiler.Start()` in `Application_BeginRequest`

But Visual Studio complains that

> 'MiniProfiler' does not contain a definition for 'Start`

So I checked the suggested [example file](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/samples/Samples.Mvc5/Global.asax.cs) and tried to imitate that but with pretty much the same results, ie

> 'MiniProfiler' does not contain a definition for 'StartNew`

What is going on here? Does this documentation need to be updated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found the answer!
Assuming we are migrating from an old Miniprofiler version to MVC5 version.

For "Start" replace:

```
MiniProfiler.Start();
```

With:

```
MiniProfiler mp = MiniProfiler.StartNew();
```

This will now give you more the sence that we are creating a new instance on the session.
For "Stop" replace:

```
MiniProfiler.Stop();
```

With:

```
MiniProfiler.Current.Stop();
```

Any action will now required to call "`MiniProfiler.Current.xxx`" to access that created MiniProfiler and do stuff. Or depending on how and where you are using it, you can call the saved MiniProfiler mp that you created earlier.